The diffraction of the Gaussian beam on a curved mirror?
I am studying diffraction. While going through multiple examples, I have understood the diffraction of plane waves passing through a finite size lens. However, it is not easy to qualitatively think about how diffraction occurs in a real case, for example, when a size larger than a Gaussian beam (such as a laser) is reflected by a concave mirror in an apparatus and how it behaves at the focal plane. One thought I had was regarding the Fraunhofer diffraction formula in the situation of passing through a circular aperture. Since the size of the aperture is large compared to the beam size, I considered changing the integration limits (in polar coordinates) from 0 to the radius to integrating from 0 to the beam width, but I find it difficult to determine if this is correct. Is there a qualitatively good approach to diffraction in the focal plane of the concave mirror which is larger than beam width for Gaussian beams?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In the paraxial approximation you can use the 2x2 beam transfer matrices (ABCD-matrices) with the complex beam parameter
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{R}-\frac{i\lambda}{\pi w^2}
\end{align}
($R$ curvature of Gauss Beam, $\lambda$ wavelength, $w$ radius) then you obtain for a thin lens
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{matrix}
q_2\\1
\end{matrix}
\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
1    & 0\\
-1/f & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
q_1\\1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{align}
or a curved mirror
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{matrix}
q_2\\1
\end{matrix}
\right)=
\left(\begin{matrix}
1    & 0\\
-2/R_e & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
q_1\\1
\end{matrix}
\right).
\end{align}
By splitting $q_2$ into real and imaginary part you can extract the new $R$ and $w$.
For details see for example "Saleh, Teich - Fundamentals of photonics".
